# Jenkins, Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket, multiple job

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I have a problem with "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket" setup on my Jenkins.

So I've configured two repositories, to start their own pipelines if someone push a commit and the push part is working, but when I create a push on repo1, it will start repo1_pipeline and repo2 pipeline.

Structure:

repo1 > repo1_pipeline

repo2 > repo2_pipeline

My url on bitbucket side (both cases): https://jenkins-url.com/bitbucket-hook/

Jenkins side:
[Jenkins setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mk7yL.png)

Someone one can u explain this for me?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

By default the Plugin will loosely match the Repository and the Job based on the SCM configurations you have. Following is from the plugin document.

> The "loose matching" is based on the host name and paths of the
> projects matching.

You can try specifying your full repository URL as the `Override Repository URL or Path`.

As an alternative, you can consider using the [Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/generic-webhook-trigger/). You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73480534/2627018) answer for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) Unfortunately I tried, but it didn't work. Do you an alternative plugin suggestion? or any other?

Comment: @gh05t please check the updated answer.